# What is the best way to move or copy test cases that have not been executed from one folder to another?

Tags: test-management, quality-center

I am using HP ALM 11.0. I have to copy a test set in test lab of QC from one folder to another but I want to preserve the status of the test cases in the new test set.

When I tried to copy and paste the test set, in the new instance all the test cases status are reset to not run by default. I want the status of the new test case to be as it was in the original test case. Can anyone help me to do this?

UPDATE: From the comments -

Our project is managed in weeks. We have a folder for each week, and the intention is to copy test cases which have not been executed the previous week into a new folder. We thought that if we copied the test set with the status we could easily remove the executed test cases.

Comment: This is the default behavior of every test case management tool I know of - could you tell us why you need to copy the status as well as the test case?

Comment: its a prj requirement we to manage our QC execution in terms of weeks means each week a new folder and cases which are not executed in the previous week should me moved to the new folder. and our intension is if we could copy the test set along with the status into the new folder then we can delete the easily delete the already executed test cases easily.

Comment: Sarvesh - I will update your question with this information. It may get you some responses.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to copy a test set in test lab of QC from one folder to another but I want to preserve the status of the test cases in the new test set.

Unfortunately, there is no way to copy a test set and preserve the test execution data from the HP ALM Client.  You have a choice to either move the test set to another folder which will preserve execution data or make a duplicate [copy] which sets all of the newly created Test Instances back to *No Run* and does not copy any of the runs.  The only way to do this would be to use the OTA Client API and write some code.

> The intention is to copy test cases which have not been executed the
>   previous week into a new folder.

You should be able to achieve your goal here.

1. Create a new test set
2. Go to the Selected Tests
3. Click on Filter/Sort

[image: HP ALM Test Lab]

1. Use a Cross Filter on Test Sets that will uniquely pick the source test set [Test Set ID]
2. Use a standard Filter to select the execution status you want to rerun [e.g. Not Passed, No Run].

[image: Cross Filter]
[image: Standard Filter]

**NOTE: This assumes that the last time you executed the test was from the source test set.  If it was run after this then the Execution Status may differ.**

The final step is just to click on the *Add Test to Test Set* button which will add only the tests from your filter.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Harrison, that totally worked!! Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Front End functionality to achieve this.

This will be possible through QC's API though and this should be doable within a day of scripting (coding ability required).